# Remove ASP.NET MVC URL routing from project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, url-routing

This is a similar question to 
["How To Disable ASP.NET MVC Url routing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550969/how-to-disable-asp-net-mvc-url-routing) which hasn't been answered (I don't think the responders understood why it was needed).

I have an existing application that uses AngularJS and MVC url routing to serve the templates. I want to remove the MVC url routing as it is redundant (see comment below. we are using webApi to return data via ajax so the views/controllers are not needed).

I have removed the call to RegisterRoutes in the Global.asax.cs. There doesn't seem to be anything in the Web.config apart from a reference to System.Web.Routing so I left it.

I am using IIS Express with Visual Studio 2012.

When the application runs I get a 403.14 Forbidden error. I have enabled directory browsing. I have set the start page in the project in Visual Studio but I get a 404 despite the file definitely being there.

I have tried creating a non-mvc website and copying the contents of the web.config to my application, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by removing the `.aspx` on the end (`www.something/home.aspx`);
In `C#`, instead of using

```
response.redirect("~/home.aspx");
```

use

```
server.transfer("~/home.aspx");
```

Comment: I'm using AngularJS which has it's own routing mechanism. I just want my existing application to behave like a normal asp.net (non-mvc) website without routing (i.e. http://localhost/index.html will serve the index.html page)

Answer (score 0):

`AngularJs` routing has nothing to do with `ASP.Net MVC Routing`.

**Angular Routing:**

> Is used for deep-linking URLs to controllers and views (HTML
>   partials). It watches $location.url() and tries to map the path to an
>   existing route definition.

**ASP.Net MVC Routing:**

> ASP.NET routing enables you to use URLs that do not have to map to
>   specific files in a Web site. Because the URL does not have to map to
>   a file, you can use URLs that are descriptive of the user's action and
>   therefore are more easily understood by users.

In essence, `AngularJs` routing deals with **client-side** routing (using the location Url), whilst `ASP.Net MVC` deals with mapping http Urls to the appropriate controller/action in the **server-side**.

Comment: Yes I know. For example, in the routing config for an Angular module we have "templateUrl: 'Customer/edit'". Normally, this would be a static file, e.g. "templateUrl: 'CustomerEdit.html'". At the moment we have an MVC CustomerController that returns a partialview. I want to remove this as it is redundant. Basically, I want a project that was created as an MVC ASP.NET website to convert back into a regular ASP.NET website. I don't want to recreate the entire project from scratch. Thanks